# Заполнить одномерный массив, случайными уникальными числами

Tags: c++, массивы, случайные-числа

Есть одномерный массив 4, его нужно заполнить рандомными числами через rand(), и они обязательно должны быть уникальными. Самое важное, все нужно сделать по шаблону который я привел ниже.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "Rus");
    srand(time(NULL));

    bool game;
    int arr[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < 4;)
        {
            game = true;
            arr[j] = rand() % 16;
            for (int k = 0; k < j; k++)
            {
                if (arr[k] == arr[j])
                {
                    game = false;
                }
            }
            if (game == true)
            {
                j++;
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Ок, задание вы показали, код написали. А в чем состоит ваш вопрос?

Comment: Надо понимать, что в массив нужно случайным образом распихать числа от 0 до 15? ну так заполните по порядку, а потом случайно перемешайте.

Comment: да можете просто генерировать через ранд индекс ячейки и туда вносить число по порядку. для увеличения рандома использовать больше ячеек и потом выбрать случайно смещение от средины например.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот, ваш код с минимальными изменениями:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    bool game;
    int arr[4][4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4;)
        {
            game = true;
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 16;
            for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++)
                for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++)
                {
                    if (r == i && c == j)
                    {
                        r = c = 4;
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (arr[r][c] == arr[i][j])
                    {
                        game = false;
                        r = c = 4;
                    }
                }
            if (game == true)
            {
                j++;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Возможный [вывод](https://ideone.com/Gmw3xd):

```
3 11 1 10 
0 15 8 4 
12 7 9 5 
13 2 14 6
```